# How can I parse out this string from a longer string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string coming in as

```
 FirstName LastLast (WorkerId)
```

so for example:

```
"Joe Thompson (234DerX)"
```

and i want to parse this out into this person object

```
 class Person
 {
      public string Name;  //Joe Thompson
      public string WorkerId;  //234DerX
 }
```

what is the best way to parse out both the worker Id and the Name.  Regex?  something simpler.  Some names have middles names or multiple first names so the only thing i can rely on is that the worker id is surrounded by "(" + ")"

Comment: It really depends on how the data is structured (of if it is structured) in the original source text.  But probably a job for regex, yes.

Comment: I'd argue it's impossible to tell without knowing **all** the variations.

Comment: Impossible if the only thing you can rely on is the format of the worker id.

Comment: EDIT: I mis-read, apologies. I thought you wanted to distinguish between first name and second name. This is really quite easy given the fact you just want to take the worker id and the rest is `Name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned inyou post `only thing i can rely on is that the worker id is surrounded by "(" + ")"` I will suggest this solution:

```
 class Person
 {
      public Person(string str)
      {
          int pos = str.LastIndexOf('(');
          Name = str.Substring(0, pos - 1);
          WorkerId = str.Substring(pos + 1).TrimEnd(')');
      }

      public string Name;
      public string WorkerId;
 }
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY the answer I was in the middle of writing. +1. Although - you need to get rid of the parentheses for the WokerId to meet OP's requirements.

Answer (score 7):

If you use regex, the following regex should do what you want:

```
@" *(?<name>.*) \((?<id>.*)\)"
```

The `Name` is stored in capturing group `name` and `WorkerId` is stored in capturing group `id`.

This assumes that worker ID is in the last pairs of parentheses.

The solution should work even if the name contains parentheses for some reason (e.g. `John (The Third) (JK4532R)`). However, it won't be able to differentiate between a name and a worker ID if the worker ID is missing in the input and the name has something in parentheses at the end (e.g. `John (The Third)`)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
var splitted = "Joe Thompson (234DerX)".Split(" ".ToCharArray(),
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var id = splitted.Last();
var name = string.Join(" ", splitted.Take(splitted.Count() - 1));
```

it will parse last part to Id and all previous to Name. You can `Trim` id from `(` and `)`

Comment: does this parse out the "(" or ")" anywhere?

Comment: @leora I don't understand question. But if you are asking, if I check for `(` - answer is no. I suppose that userId is last entry.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then you can simply split the string on intervals, then take the last resulting string, trim it from brackets front and back and you will have the id. 
As for the name, since you do not know exactly how many names there are, it will be harder if you want to put only some of them in the string. If you just need the first of the first names and the last of the last names then just take the first and the second-to-last string in the array resulting from the split.

Something like this:

```
var splitArray = "Joe Thompson (234DerX)".Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var id = splitArray.Last().Trim(new char['(',')']);
var name = splitArray[0] + " " + splitArray[splitArray.Length - 2];

var person = new Person();
person.Id = id;

person.Name = name;
```

Comment: Ok, I've added it. Was it really necessary to vote down?

Comment: Erm...yes. Your answer was bad, that's how this voting thing works.

Comment: No, sorry, I see what your getting at.

Answer (score 0):

If it's so simple, I think regex is an overkill...

```
int idStart = personStr.IndexOf('(');
int idEnd = personStr.IndexOf(')');
Name = personStr.SubString(0, idStart);
WorkerId = personStr.SubString(idStart + 1, idEnd - idStart);
```

Of course, you have to validate that peronStr is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Split method like this:-

```
var split = yourString.Split(new char[] {"("});
```

Please read MSDN doc. for more info about split memory allocation impact. [MSDN Split documentaion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
    string hld = "Joe Thompson (234DerX)";

    char[] separator = new char[] { '(' };
    string[] strSplitArr;


    strSplitArr = hld.Split(separator);

    string Name = strSplitArr[0].ToString();
    string WorkerId = strSplitArr[1].ToString().Replace(")", "");
```